# How to remove GRPC object so that multiprocessing works?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, grpc, grpc-python

GRPC does [not support](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/16001) python `multiprocessing`.

I wanted to work around this by making a GRPC call from a process and then 
closing the channel and deleting all references to the GRPC objects so that they do not get pickled.

However, I get dreaded

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/edgar/miniconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 236, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "/home/edgar/miniconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PickleError: can't pickle repeated message fields, convert to list first
```

**Is it possible to remove all GRPC objects after using them so that I can use multiprocessing?**

**If not, what do I not understand about the issues of GRPC and multiprocessing?**

The code looks like this. I can create a minimal working example if that proves essential.

```
def run_env(env_id: str, queue: multiprocessing.Queue, predictor_address: str, id: str = '-1'):
    # Create environment
    env = er.create_env_from_id(env_id=env_id)

    # Run Forest, Run
    state = env.reset()
    done = False
    while not done:
        done = True
        action = get_prediction(state=state, predictor_address=predictor_address)
        new_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        tup = (id, state, action, reward, new_state, done)
        queue.put(tup)

        if done:
            state = env.reset()
            done = False


def get_prediction(state: np.ndarray, predictor_address: str) -> np.ndarray:
    with grpc.insecure_channel(predictor_address, options=options) as channel:
        stub = pgrpc.MlAgentPredictorStub(channel)
        action_pb = stub.Predict(get_state(nstate=state))

    action = action_pb.action
    del action_pb
    return action

def env_test():
    predictor_address = 'localhost:50051'
    runners = []
    pqueue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    for ii in range(2):
        args = ('Test', pqueue, predictor_address, str(ii), )
        runner = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_env, args=args)
        runner.daemon = True
        runner.start()
        runners.append(runner)
```